# Change image in code with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I've tried a few different methods based on the official documentation and from debugging my if/else condition is firing correctly, but I can't seem to get my image to change.

As you can see, I've tried two methods here but my understanding is that `ImageSource.FromFile` isn't needed because of implicit conversion.

Here's the XAML:

```xml
<TableView Intent="Settings">
        <TableRoot>
            <TableSection Title="Getting Started">
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10" >
                        <Image Source="bulb.png" x:Name="imgBulb" />
                        <Switch x:Name="bulbSwitch" IsToggled="false" Toggled="bulbSwitchToggled" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </TableSection>
            <TableSection Title="Time to slide....">
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="10" >
                        <Slider Maximum="100" Minimum="0" Value="50" ValueChanged="sliderChanged" ></Slider>
                        <Label x:Name="lblSliderOutput" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="Placeholder" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </TableSection>
        </TableRoot>
    </TableView>
```

And the code behind:

```
public partial class TableViewsPage : ContentPage
{
    public TableViewsPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        lblSliderOutput.Text = "50";
    }

    public void sliderChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args) {
        var simpleValue = Convert.ToInt32 (args.NewValue);
        lblSliderOutput.Text = simpleValue.ToString();
    }

    public void bulbSwitchToggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs args) {
        if (imgBulb.Source == ImageSource.FromFile("bulb.png"))
        {
            imgBulb.Source = ImageSource.FromFile ("biggerBulb.png");
            Debug.WriteLine ("imgbulb = bulb.png");
        } 
        else 
        {
            imgBulb.Source = "bulb.png";
            Debug.WriteLine ("imgbulb = biggerBulb.png");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can compare an ImageSource like that.  Why wouldn't you just use the IsToggled state of the switch to determine  which image to show?

Comment: Thanks, that seems the most obvious!